# using Spotify's webAPI in an iOS app

Tags: spotify

So I'm in the process of developing an iOS app and I wanted to use the Spotify web API for searching and looking up songs in Spotify. However, I can't really tell if that is how to do it or if there would be better ways to do it and wanted to clarify before I began. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like the use the Web API, it works just the same as any other JSON REST API, so a lot of the tutorials out there for doing that on iOS will help you just fine. For converting between JSON and Objective-C data structures, newer iOS versions have `NSJSONSerialization`, otherwise I can recommend the open-source `TouchJSON`.

Also, you might want to look at CocoaLibSpotify, which is an Objective-C library for interacting with the Spotify service in a much more integrated way than the Web API — including music streaming. However, it does require a Spotify user be logged in to use.